# Como testar a conexão ao banco de dados Mysql (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python-3.x, testes-de-unidade, sqlalchemy

Comecei a aprender testes unitários recentemente, **Não** sei se teste unitário é realmente o termo que procuro, mas como eu posso "testar" a conexão com banco de dados ?

Answer (score -1):

Conexão com o banco de dados normalmente não é um negócio que você testa nos seus testes unitários. A biblioteca SQLAlchemy certamente já tem um teste pra isso. Você testaria, por exemplo, se uma dada função retorna o registro mais recente do banco de dados, ou ainda se outra função realmente insere um novo registro no banco de dados.

Lembre-se que testes que usam banco de dados são mais lentos, o que pode desestimular outros programadores de os rodarem frequentemente. Uma alternativa pra agilizar é substituindo o banco de produção (MySQL, PostgreSQL...) por um banco SQLite em memória. Outra alternativa pra melhorar muito a performance dos testes é criar uma camada de serviço que abstrai a interação com o banco, daí você pode usar um mock quando precisar acessar o banco. De bônus você ganha um código mais desacoplado da camada de persistência, o que facilitaria muito numa eventual mudança de banco de dados (de MySQL pra MongoDB por exemplo).

Pra configurar o SQLAlchemy para rodar com SQLite e/ou MySQL/PostgreSQL, você pode fazer assim:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(os.environ['DB_URL'])
```

Em produção a variável de ambiente ficaria assim:

```
DB_URL="postgresql://db-user:db-password@db-host:5432/db-name"
```

Pra rodar os testes ficaria assim:

```
DB_URL="sqlite://"
```

Não esqueça de reconstruir o banco de dados e as tabelas antes de cada execução de teste. O projeto [Factory Alchemist](https://bitbucket.org/sievetech/factory-alchemist/src/master/) é um bom exemplo de como consegue rodar testes usando banco de dados com o SQLAlchemy.